# I can't install Anaconda in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

After downloading Anaconda (for Python) in Ubuntu 14.04 from the website continuum.io/downloads and I click on the file 
file:///home/nikolokas/Downloads/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86.s‌​h in order to execute it, an empty non-responding window opens with the file's name as a title with the extension "- gedit" and I have to force quit. The file has been saved at the Downloads. The problem has nothing to do with the version of Anaconda, as I have observed. Can anyone help me proceed to the installation?

Answer (score 2):

On the download page, next to the download button (left) it shows how to install on Linux. [Anaconda Download](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#linux)

Open a terminal in the folder you downloaded the sh file and type:

**for python 3.5**

```
sudo bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

**for python 2.7**

```
sudo bash Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Type your administrator password at the prompt then follow the instructions in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you. I gave permission to the file to run as a program and then I opened the terminal window and pasted the file's title (bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh) and (sudo bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh), but the file wasn't found, although it is in the Downloads folder. What do you mean by "Open a terminal in the folder you downloaded the sh file"? The Terminal is an application, so how is it associated with the Downloads folder?

Comment: If you use your explorer to navigate to the downloads folder, then right click the folder, you can chose "open terminal here". This will open a terminal at the correct location. Otherwise you need to open terminal and use cd commands to the files location.

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal and copy and paste either one of the two scripts below (depending on whether you want python 2 or python 3. Basically wget downloads anaconda and the rest goes through the installation process for you. source .bashrc basically refreshes your terminal so you dont have to close and open your terminal to use the conda or python commands

[python 2 anaconda install bash script](https://gist.github.com/mGalarnyk/4e48b0dc307a2d50f4b7701dbc54573d):

```
# Go to home directory
cd ~

# You can change what anaconda version you want at 
# https://repo.continuum.io/archive/
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/anaconda
rm Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
echo 'export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc 

# Refresh basically
source .bashrc

conda update conda
```

[python 3 anaconda install bash script](https://gist.github.com/mGalarnyk/05e4147b7fdfe4f94863e693644b43d9)

```
# Go to home directory
cd ~

# You can change what anaconda version you want at 
# https://repo.continuum.io/archive/
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/anaconda
rm Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
echo 'export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc 

# Refresh basically
source .bashrc

conda update conda
```

Source: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-python-on-ubuntu-anaconda-65623042cb5a